# How to Query ">", "<" and "<>" in Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene, lucene.net, querying

Is is possible to query like : age>23 in lucene?

I have been looking into it but I couldn't find anything, can someone guide me through in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for,

```
age:[23 TO *] finds all field values greater than or equal to 23
```

Comment: Also make sure your 'age' field is indexed as an IntField.